# When disabling submit button form is not submitting

Tags: jquery, html, forms, onclick, form-submit

I found this code to prevent double submit a form, but this code is not working as it should, it is disabling the submit button and changing the button value to "Please wait" but it is also submitting  form.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="reply" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Please Wait...';" />
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `return false;` at the end. Also, when should it submit if not when you click it?

Comment: Actually when the button is clicked it takes some time to refresh the form and if in that time the button is clicked the form is submitted again, so i just want the form to submit once either by disabling the button or totally hiding it

Answer (score 2):

```
$("form").on("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find("[type='submit']").attr("disabled","disabled").attr("value","Please wait");
  if(everything is ok) //you didn't specify what this is in your question.
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Comment: what should be specified in this line    if(everything is ok)

Comment: @Yaser what do you need to do before submitting? If you don't want to do anything, just delete the if statement

Answer (score 0):

for anyone concerned i found this way and it worked for me

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="reply_ticket" class="btn" onclick="this.style.visibility = 'hidden'" />
```

just add this to the button or input works either way